# Tor encoding for national (cyrillic) symbols it torrc

Tags: configuration

When I firstly run tor browser, it modifies the torrc file. It writes

```
"C:\\Users\\\300\355\344\360\345\351\\Desktop\\tor"
```

for my C:\Users\Андрей\Desktop\tor (Андрей => \300\355\344\360\345\351). What is the encoding of this sequence? My torrc file encoded in UTF8 w/o BOM, is this wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tor encodes all cyrillic symbols in CP-1251, represented as octal numbers and escaped by reversed slashes.